# Phpdoc for variable "cast"?

Tags: php, phpdoc

base classes:

```
abstract class A
{
    public function methodA() { echo __FUNCTION__.'<br>'; }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function methodB() { echo __FUNCTION__.'<br>'; }
}
```

so far so good.
A factory which can create any of them:

```
class Factory
{
    /**
     * @return A
     */
    public static function createAorB()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

phpdoc is right, since it say "return something comes from `A`".
Now the tricky part comes:

```
class OwnClass
{
    /**
     * @var A
     */
    protected $var;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->var = \Factory::createAorB();
    }
}

class OwnClassB extends OwnClass
{
    public function callMe()
    {
        $this->var->methodA();
        $this->var->methodB(); // this will also run, but IDE wont autocomplete with this method
    }
}

(new OwnClassB())->callMe();
```

this will run for sure, but check for the `methodB()` calling. IDE wont autocomplete with this method. How to tell that var is now `B`, not `A` with phpDoc?

Comment: Not clear how `@return A` is actually correct, when you're returning `B`?  PHPStorm (at least) would properly autocomplete if you had `@var B` on your `protected $var` variable...  (tested and proven in PHPStorm.  Lints properly, and auto-completes properly with this one change).

Comment: @cale_b It's correct since `A` is part of the inheritance chain of `B`. The phpdoc only says that the method will return a class conforming to the definition of class A. B does that (since it extends A). Which is also the reason why PHPStorm won't autocomplete - since you can't assume that `methodB` exists from the current hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override inherited properties for PHPStorm's autocompletion:

```
/**
 * @property B $var
 */
class OwnClassB extends OwnClass
{
    //...
}
```

However, I personally think you're trying to solve the wrong problem. If you have a Factory class that returns *either* `A` or `B`, you shouldn't type hint the return value to `A`. Instead, you should provide both:

```
class Factory
{
    /**
     * @return A|B
     */
    public static function createAorB()
    {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Both options inform PHPStorm enough to let it show you both methods as autocomplete options, but the latter is accurate in terms of what the code actually does (well, not in this example, but given the function name I guess that's what your real-world implementation does).

Comment: hinting both A and B is wrong, since it may return with a future C, D .... classes

Comment: Ok, in that case it would be counterproductive to hint `A|B|C|D` because you'd probably end up with a lot of autocomplete options that do not actually apply. Then the first option is probably a better choice.